# AS3: Inefficient to make too many references across classes?

Tags: performance, class, actionscript-3, actionscript, processing-efficiency

I was told once that I should avoid referencing properties and such of my main game class from other classes as much as possible because it's an inefficient thing to do. Is this actually true? For a trivial example, in my Character class would

`MainGame.property = something;
MainGame.property2 = something2;
MainGame.property3 = something3;
//etc.`

take more time to execute than putting the same in a function

`MainGame.function1();`

and calling that (thereby needing to "open" that class only once rather than multiple times)? By the same logic, would

`something = MainGame.property;
something2 = MainGame.property;`

be slightly less efficient than

`variable = MainGame.property;
something = variable;
something2 = variable;`?

Comment: I would also like to know this. Specifically, if I have a var that originates from Main.as and is passed to all of my movieclip scenes. All of which inherit CoreScene with the var as an internal to be specific

Comment: These is a great example of pre-mature optimization. You aren't going to run into performance problems with either approach, performance problems will rise from a different flaw. (BTW, a function call is more expensive than a property assignment. But again, your critical performance optimization is not going to be deciding between those two things.)

Comment: @Aaron Premature optimization for sure if you're thinking about it too much early on, but the time for optimization may eventually be mature and then it might be helpful to know. What about: `Main.property` more expensive than `this.property`?

Answer (score 1):

Think of referencing things as of operations. Every "." is an operation, every function call "()" is an operation (and a heavy one), every "+", "-" and so on.

So, indeed, certain approaches will generate more efficient code than other ones.

But. The thing is, to feel the result of inefficient approach you need to create a program performing millions of operations (or heavy tasks of the appropriate difficulty) each frame. If you are not parsing megabytes of binary data, or converting bitmaps, or such, you can not worry about performance. Although worrying about performance and efficiency is generally a good thing to do.

If you are willing to measure the efficiency of your code, you are free to measure its performance:

```
var aTime:int;

var a:int = 10;
var b:int = 20;
var c:int;
var i:int;
var O:Object;

aTime = getTimer();
O = new Object;

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    O.ab = a + b;
    O.ba = a + b;
}

trace("Test 1. Elapsed", getTimer() - aTime, "ms.");

aTime = getTimer();
O = new Object;
c = a + b;

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    O.ab = c;
    O.ba = c;
}

trace("Test 2. Elapsed", getTimer() - aTime, "ms.");

aTime = getTimer();
O = new Object;

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    O['ab'] = a + b;
    O['ba'] = a + b;
}

trace("Test 3. Elapsed", getTimer() - aTime, "ms.");
```

Be prepared to run million-iteration loops so that total execution time exceeds 1 second, otherwise the precision will be too low.